# Why is this C for-loop not working properly?

Tags: c, for-loop, input, scanf, freeze

```
int main()
{
    int t, i;
    int *nums;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    nums = malloc(t * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &nums[i]);          
    }
    printf("hey");
}
```

For some reason, it hangs, waiting for more input! Any ideas?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75968/discussion-on-question-by-antoni4040-why-is-this-c-for-loop-not-working-properly).

Comment: @Wather Vane thats correct but using Visual C++ doesn't either compile without the cast. So it was a suggestion.

Comment: It is working with me. I'm using visual studio 2010.

Comment: Show us what exactly you are typing. This might show the actual problem.

Comment: In chat, OP's comments "No... BTW, if I add a printf in the loop that prints the current input, it prints everything except from the last one...".  1) So I have to ask simply, did you press <Enter> after the last number?  2) Try adding a `'\n'` to `printf("hey");` --> `printf("hey\n");`.

Comment: @chux , Post an answer. @OP, Or use `fflush(stdout);` just after the last `printf`

Comment: @Antoni4040 I assume when you commented "That worked!" that you are referring to #2 "adding a `'\n'`".  If you meant #1 (adding <Enter>) let me know.

Comment: I meant that adding '\n' finally fixed the problem... Not sure why...

Answer (score 1):

This code is correct, except for the fact that you're not freeing your memory (not a big issue for this simple code) and you're not checking `scanf` for errors, which may be the cause of your problem.

A better implementation with error checking and correct memory handling is described below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int t, i, ret;
    int *nums;

    ret = scanf("%d", &t);          
    if(ret != 1)
    {
        /* something wrong */
    }

    nums = malloc(t * sizeof(int));
    if(nums==NULL)
    {
        /* memory error */
    }

    for(i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        ret = scanf("%d", &nums[i]);          
        if(ret != 1)
        {
            /* something wrong */
        }

    }
    free(nums);
    printf("hey");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why it hangs on scanf or which scanf it is hanging on.

Comment: It hangs even if I write it like this: int nums[5]

Comment: It says that "it hangs, waiting for more input", so this hanging is very dubious.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess here...

But I'm guessing you ran it and entered :

```
4
1234
```

For example, you put in 4 and then 1234 and it hangs. Well, that would be because 1234 is the first number and not 4 distinct numbers so its waiting for the second number. You have to press enter or some such delimiter between each number.

Try this set of inputs instead:

```
4
1234
29
4
5
```

You should get :

```
hey
```

Pro grammatically, you should be checking return values from your function calls.   Make sure malloc didn't return zero.  Make sure scanf returns the number of inputs you expected to read.   Add in printouts to make sure the values it read in are what you expected/wanted to read in.

EDIT : 
Guessing you have a typo in the program which isn't displayed here.   such as :

```
scanf("%s", &t);
```

Or you are getting the 'hey' and just not seeing it.

```
[ov@MARVIN sotest]$ ./a.out
5 5 4 3 23 1
hey[ov@MARVIN sotest]$
```

See the 'hey' is sort of hidden in my prompt because you are missing the '\n' new line in the printout?

Comment: Did you literally enter a space between each number or did you hit return?

Answer (score 1):

Remember to flush when you are done.

In chat, OP's comments "No... BTW, if I add a printf in the loop that prints the current input, it prints everything except from the last one...".  This hinted that the issue was on the final output.

The following sends data out to be printed.  But `stdout` is typically buffered.  Actual output may not occur until sometime later.  Output is *flushed* when  1) output contains an end-of-line `'\n'`, 2) `fflush()` is called 3) the program ends.  I am surprised output did not appear when the program ended, but possibly OP's true code differs from the post.

```
printf("hey");
```

Change to

```
printf("hey\n");
```

Or [@Cool Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049655/cool-guy)

```
printf("hey");
fflush(stdout);
```

BTW: This is also hinted in [@Diversity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29805593/2410359) answer.

---

Note: Always a good idea to check the result of `scanf()`

```
// scanf("%d", &t)
if (1 != scanf("%d", &t)) Handle_BadInput_or_EOF();
```